# How to get access token in firebase login with provider

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up login on my app with firebase, i'm choose Github provider for my login provider. I try to debug and access data from debug variable but can't access from code. here my code:

```
var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
var provider: OAuthProvider.Builder = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("github.com")

// login handler
        btn_login.setOnClickListener {
            firebaseAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider(this, provider.build())
                .addOnSuccessListener{ result: AuthResult ->
                    System.out.println(result.credential)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                        exception -> print(exception)
                }
        }
```

and System.out:

```
I/System.out: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWebException: The web operation was canceled by the user.com.google.firebase.auth.zzg@588c9c4
```

From debug I found where the access token is, but I can't access it.

```
((result as zzh).zzc as zzg).accessToken
//399kdkkda0XXXXX
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: solved, add this `val token = result.credential as OAuthCredential`

Comment: This works! I had the same problem just now for Microsoft login, casting the Credential property to OAuthCredential works to expose the property.